# Samsung Internet open links on it own and pop up as picture in picture

Tags: malware, popup, virus

My phone pop up ads page every 5 minutes in Samsung Internet as picture in picture mode, I tried to find any app doing this but nothing was found, any idea on how to get rid of this?[image: ad popup]